# Using Datastore's pagination example causes " Error: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: invalid encoding"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using [this page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-datastore-cursor-paging-nodejs) as a starting point.

My code looks like this:

```
app.get('/gizmos', async (req, res, next) => {

  const pageSize = 3;
  const resText = [];
  const cursor = req.query.cursor;

  try {
    let query = datastore.createQuery('gizmo').limit(pageSize);

    if (cursor) {
      query = query.start(cursor);
    }

    const [results] = await datastore.runQuery(query);
    const [gizmos] = results[0];

    const info = results[1];

    if (info.moreResults !== Datastore.NO_MORE_RESULTS) {
    // If there are more results to retrieve, the end cursor is
    // automatically set on `info`. To get this value directly, access
    // the `endCursor` property.
        const nextUrl = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + req.baseUrl + "?cursor=" + info.endCursor;
        console.log(nextUrl);
    }

    gizmos.forEach(gizmo => {

      const id = gizmo[Datastore.KEY].id;

      resText.push({
         "id" : id,
         "name" : gizmo.name,
  
      });

    });

    res
      .status(200)
      .set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
      .send(resText)
      .end();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

But it fails with a `500` error. The logs say this:

> Error: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: invalid
> encoding      at Object.callErrorFromStatus
> (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
> at Object.onReceiveStatus
> (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52)
> at Object.onReceiveStatus
> (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
> at Object.onReceiveStatus
> (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
> at
> /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)

Any ideas?

Comment: Random guess is that the problem is that you are passing an array in res.send(), but res.send() is expecting a string.  send(JSON.stringify(resText)) may fix it.

Comment: Is this line being logged `console.log(nextUrl);`? If so then the query is being executed correctly and the reason might be what was commented above.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue and none of the answers solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki as it's based on @JimMorrison's comment.

The issue here is that you are passing an array in your `res.send()`, but it is expecting a string, given the `text/plain` content type, so you need to convert this array into a string before using it here. You can do that by doing using the following code:

```
res
  .status(200)
  .set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  .send(JSON.stringify(resText))
  .end();
```

Answer (score 1):

The info.endCursor may contain reserved Characters

`var set1 = ";,/?:@&=+$";  // Reserved Characters`

Change the code of your http request to `"?cursor=" + encodeURIComponent(info.endCursor);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the cursor via query string, which should be encoded and decoded via `encodeURIComponent` / `decodeURIComponent`.

**Decoding:**

```
if (cursor) {
  query = query.start(decodeURIComponent(cursor));
}
```

**Encoding:**

```
encodeURIComponent(info.endCursor)
```